# Default values for res/values/colors.xml in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

For some reason, the colors.xml file within an android studio project i am working on was corrupted, and now the app wont build, i haven't added any new colors, so all i need is the default values for the file.

Example of Error:

```
error: resource color/colorPrimaryDark (aka com.example.ciscoappprototype:color/colorPrimaryDark) not found.
```

Comment: Just define `<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#......</color>`

Comment: I was about to comment what @GabrieleMariotti said. Please do that and try to rebuild

Comment: if its corrupted try cleaning your project`(build > Clean Project)` and build it again `(build > Rebuild Project)`. If the problem still persist, try `(File > Invalidate Caches / Restart)`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="primary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="primary_dark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="accent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

Some more may be missing, but that is the idea, the file is located inside:

```
app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml
```

You may have some more missing, but you can fix them by building, viewing the error and adding the missing color xml property.

Furthermore, please invest in a good backup solution, if this type of project can be public, then use Git. It is free and is fantastic to use. GitHub desktop is the client I use for it.

Comment: "if this type of project can be public, then use Git" `git` can be used for private projects as well. "private" vs "public" depends on the host you use, not on `git` itself.

Comment: Git is a source control system, not a backup solution. Services like GitHub and BitBucket allow you to push your git repository to a remote server.